# Bypassing XSRF token check

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jira, csrf

I am attempting to utilize jQuery AJAX to POST dynamic data into JIRA. The idea is to POST to the JIRA REST API via "rest/api/2/issue/".

I believe I have all of my jQuery laid out properly. The issue I'm having trouble getting past is the "XSRF token check" upon execution. Every time I attempt to run my code, it returns "XSRF token check failed" from the server.

I have read about the "X-Atlassian-Token" header. I have that as an allowed header on my jira server config. i.e...

'Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Atlassian-Token, Authorization, Content-Type"'

I have also set the header on my AJAX request. "X-Atlassian-Token": "no-check"

Can someone assist me in getting this to work properly?
JIRA version tested with is 6.4.12.

My current AJAX code is below for review.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://my-jira-host.com/rest/api/2/issue/",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    headers: {
      "X-Atlassian-Token": "nocheck",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("<username>:<password>")
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({"fields":{"project":{"key":"CLS"},"priority":{"name":"Minor"},"customfield_17125":{"value":"<Department>"},"customfield_17127":"<HOSTNAME>","customfield_17126":{"value":"<Object>"},"issuetype":{"name":"<issue-type>"},"customfield_17128":"dsfgfdsg","summary":"Department | HOSTNAME | Object","description":"sdfgfdg"}}),
    success: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("POST was a success!");
      console.log("HTTP Error Message: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      console.log("HTTP Status: " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("POST was a failure!");
      console.log("HTTP Error Message: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
      console.log("HTTP Status: " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
    }
  });
```

I should also mention that this code is being sent from client website I created internally. Both client front-end and JIRA host are on the same internal network.

Answer (score 2):

XSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) is a security feature used by Jira to prevent users from being tricked into submitting malicious data.

If you are using Firefox or Chrome, you may need to set the User-Agent with a dummy value like this:

```
headers: {
  "X-Atlassian-Token": "nocheck",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("<username>:<password>"),
  "User-Agent": "xx"
},
```

Comment: but setting it - is not allowed

Comment: I still see the same issue, added the mentioned headers. No success